# jsTree contextmenu does not work along with jsTreeGrid

Tags: jstree

I am new to jsTree. As I am in need to represent the node types also along with node names, I have moved to jsTreeGrid. I am in a need to create nodes, rename, delete, edit the tree nodes as well as edit the node types in the second column of the jsTreeGrid. Somehow I could edit the second column (ie.,type column) but the jsTree just displays the contextmenu but their corresponding functions are not called. Help on this would be very useful. Here is my code:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var data;

            data = [{
                text: "Satellite City",
                data: {type: "<b>Project</b>", size: "30",spanclass:"root"},
                children: [
                    {text: "Phase-1", data: {type: "<i>Phase</i>", size: "50",spanclass:"first"}},
                    {text: "Phase-2", data: {type: "<i>Phase</i>", size: "50",spanclass:"second"}, children:[
                        {text:"Ruby Towers",data:{type: "<i>Tower</i>",size:"50",spanclass:"third"}}
                    ]}
                ]
            }];


            $("div#container").jstree({
                plugins: ["themes", "json", "grid", "dnd", "contextmenu", "search"],
                core: {
                    data: data
                },
                grid: {
                    columns: [
                        {width: 300, header: "WBS Tree",title:"_DATA_"},
                        {width: 100, 
                         cellClass: "col1", 
                         value: "type", 
                         header: "<i>Node Type</i>",                
                         valueClass:"spanclass"                                        
                        },
                    ],
                    resizable:true,
                    contextmenu:true
                },
                dnd: {
                    drop_finish : function () { 
                    }, 
                    drag_finish : function () { 
                    }, 
                    drag_check : function (data) { 
                        return { 
                            after : true, 
                            before : true, 
                            inside : true 
                        }; 
                    } 
                }
            });

            $("input#search").keyup(function (e) {
                var tree = $("div#container").jstree();
                tree.search($(this).val());
            });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be in the jsTree config. Try adding `"check_callback": true` to its `core`.

Or check out working fiddle - [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/2wLLL6hk/).

Comment: Adding "check_callback": true to jsTree config allows me to create new nodes only within the tree but their corresponding grid elements columns are not editable (the menu with 'Edit' option is available). When I try to edit the second column, it throws the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null. A suggestion to avoid this error may help me complete my work. I think while creating the tree node, we may have to either add  the type or provide some type by default so that the column can be easily edited. Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: I can edit second column in my fiddle absolutely fine. Please check same fiddle again. I also added the third column. It also works there.

Comment: Hi Ermakov, I analysed your JS Fiddle. I could see you adding third column and editing the 2nd or 3rd columns of the node defined in the data. Have you tried to edit 2nd or 3rd columns of  newly created nodes? I could add new nodes but not edit for values in 2nd or 3rd columns. I don't see you doing this in your Fiddle.

Comment: That's because we also need to pass `data` object with settings for columns to a newly created node. `Type` it was looking for is the value parameter for your columns. Please check the fiddle again. Now it works as you planned - [https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/2wLLL6hk/](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/2wLLL6hk/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ermakov!!! I will use the 'create_node.jstree event handling function and concentrate on other aspects of my project.

Comment: To do this please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I am facing the same issue of not getting the contextmenu functionality when the data is loaded from an external file. The contextmenu options are displayed, but selecting them does not produce the required results. The fiddle gives the code in which the json data file is loaded from the file 'savedtree.json'. Anyway the jsfiddle does not work as I cannot load the file 'savedtree.json': https://jsfiddle.net/vsanandan/rpgsn6yd/1/

Comment: Hi, can you paste your json somewhere?

Comment: Hi Nikolay, The json file is given in the javascript section of the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsanandan/wgzzLobz/

Comment: Hi! You have to change the `value` property in your grid config to `value` like: `value: "value"` for you cells (earlier you have used `type` like `value: "type"`). Check fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/f6qumped/.

Comment: Thanks again Nikolay. As I was keep trying with changes in accessing the json file, when I tried like this  'url': function(node) {
                      return 'savedtree.json';
                  }, within the 'data' of 'core', I could get the contextmenu working. Of course I changed from          value:"type"  to value:"value".